# Vue & Laravel - Pass prop to a constant

Tags: laravel, vuejs3

I'm passing posts from controller to a Vue component:

```
public function show(Post $post)
    {
        return Inertia::render('Post/Show', ['post' => $post]);
    }
```

In my vue file I have this:

```
<script>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'

export default {
    props: {
     post: Object
    }
}

const article = ref(post)
```

But this throws an error: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: post is not defined.

How do I pass my post obj and assign it to the article constant?

I tried props.post but that isn't the solution, I'm very new to Vue and I'm mostly focused on backend stuff.

Comment: `const article = ref(post)` post is not a standalone variable. If you try to access it from within the export context, you need to call `this.post`. If you want to get the post from another context, you need to use the reference name for the exported content.

Comment: @Techno Can you explain more please? What code I should use?

Comment: If you can add to the question what your full vue file export looks like, and where you are trying to use the article constant, I can look into it

Comment: @Techno This is the original file: https://github.com/TylerPottsDev/yt-vue-quiz/blob/master/src/App.vue I'm taking everything there but needed the quiz JSON data to come from database, which it does through the controller